# CSS Aligning Dynamic Div

Tags: css

Having a little issue with floating and a responsive layout.  I have a div container that has a left and right div container inside.  The two have to be on the same "row" but when div container "RIGHT" is set to 100%, it moves it down to the next row.  I have made a quick fiddle here.

http://jsfiddle.net/v5tnshjw/1/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="leftBox">LEFT</div>
    <div class="rightBox">RIGHT</div>
</div>

.row {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto; 
}
.leftBox {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 80px;
}
.rightBox {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The box on the right needs to flow with the browser width but stay on the same line.

Any help or pointers would be great!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the inner divs to `display:table-cell` with the parent as `display:table` and `table-layout:fixed`:

```css
.row {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.leftBox {
    display:table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 80px;
}
.rightBox {
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="leftBox">LEFT</div>
    <div class="rightBox">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [CSS3 `calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) :

```css
.row {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto; 
}
.leftBox {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 80px;
}
.rightBox {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="leftBox">LEFT</div>
    <div class="rightBox">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works also.  Thanks for the tip! Never knew this was out there.

Answer (score 0):

If the left box also needs to scale:

```
.row {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto; 
    }
.leftBox {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20%;
}
.rightBox {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Although this does work. the left needs to be static.